# is it possible to debug other apps in a jailbreak iphone using the gdb in xcode? remote debugging?

Tags: iphone, ios, gdb, jailbreak

is it possible to debug other apps in a jailbreak iphone using the gdb in xcode? remote debugging?
No version of gdb works with ios 6.1... 
Which are the other ways to use gdb in ios 6.1?

Comment: IDApro would the weapon of choice for reversing other apps.

Comment: Yes but you can't debug an iOS app

Comment: Yes you can, just it is really tough to do. Just because you dont have the original sources does not mean that you cant change the functionality (reverse engineering, disassemble, reassemble).

Comment: I want to debug an app with gdb to track all the calls to the objc_msgSend functions... that's my question... can ida do that? I think that you don't understand my question...

Answer (score 3):

You have to install debugserver (iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Debugserver) on your iDevice in order to be able to debug an application remotely.
With IDA's you can attach with "remote gdb debugger" to the debugserver running on the iDevice. I have gotten it to connect with IDA to the debugserver, unfortunatelly this is as far as it goes. Something in IDA's remote gdb debugger is not compliant with sending commands. I think this has to do with this (sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Darwin.html) which describes that gdb has to be set up for debugging darwin. IDA doesn't do this and so it doesn't synch correctly with the debugserver that is running on the iDevice. Using the native gnu gdb client works though, but I think it's lack of GUI is tedious and that getting it to work in IDA would be great. You can also connect to the debugserver using LLDB (lldb.llvm.org) which gives you somewhat more control than using gdb.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In order to debug iphone apps on ios6, you need to use gdb. im not sure what you mean by when you ask if ida can do that. IDA disassembles an IDA file. to decrypt it, you must crack the app using clutch or rasticrac on iPhone. in order to debug, you have to use GDB. Yes, all of these CAN be done on ios 6.1 jailbroken.

Comment: the question is asking how to debug using gdb.

Answer (score 0):

Ida isn't only a disassembler, it is also a very capable debugger.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be able to remote debug using debugserver.